# Manually obtaining information about Linux File Descriptor Table

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, file-descriptor

How can I obtain the file descriptor flags 'fd flags' residing in the File Descriptor Table associated with any open file descriptor? I would like to know to write the code manually or at least what functions and structures to research further while not using the fcntl function or viewing the /proc entries.

The image below shows that the file descriptor table for a given process has a flags field and a file pointer field. How can I programatically access these fields?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can access `/proc/PID/fdinfo/FD` file which contains `flags` in octal:

```
$ cat /proc/$$/fdinfo/0
pos:    0
flags:  0100002
mnt_id: 20
```

In this example, `0100002 = O_LARGFILE|O_RDWR`

Comment: Just edited my question, is it possible to do this without viewing the proc directory?

Answer (score 0):

`fcntl()` is a system call, not "a library". It *is* the way you retrieve the flags associated with a file descriptor.